# Debug.Assert sometimes does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have the following issue with a Debug.Assert ine in a function

```
public override ReportErrorLevel GenerateResults(bool reformat) {
...
   for (int Col = MinResultsCol; Col < MaxResultsCol + 1; Col++) {
      try {
         ReportColumnTitle ColTitle = ColumnInfo[Col];

         #if DEBUG
         Debug.Assert(ColTitle.BreakOnGenerate, "...");
         #endif

         ...
      } catch ...
   }
}
```

I use this so that I can set a value in the column and then run a report, when the system reaches the column it breaks.

I get occasions when this is not caught, however when I set an unconditional breakpoint before the loop, then run once it is reached, the assertion is then caught (in this case the 15th time through the loop).

(the #if DEBUG is there since ReportColumnTitle.BreakOnGenerate is also in a #if DEBUG section) - I am not asking for a view on whether this is correct:)

This is not consistent other than having set the breakpoint, the assertion then seems to be thrown every time correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior matches a problem in the debugger in VS2008 SP1.  There was [a hotfix](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB967631) released for it.  It came back in VS2010, its SP1 fixed it again.  Both the hotfix and SP1 are known to be quite stable and take care of debugger problems, I strongly recommend you install it.

Comment: thanks, whilst the hotfix doesn't specifically mention the symptoms I have found, there are enough similarities to be worth a try.

Comment: I installed the hotfix, it did not help.  
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional
Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-270-8137934-60076
Microsoft Visual C# 2008
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB967631)   KB967631

Comment: I have the same problem with the same version of VS2008. I have installed the hotfix but it hasn't helped. I can run my program twice and one time it will assert and the other time it won't, although absolutely nothing has changed. Does anyone know if there is a fix for this (that works)?

Comment: I also have the same problem using VS2008 9.0.30729.1 SP. I have installed the hotfix but it had no effect. No threading. I can't narrow down the problem at all - sometimes the asserts work, sometimes they don't. It's driving me nuts! Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Seems to have this problem. VS2010 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel. SP doesn't help